# Magento 2 : Make customer name optional while creating customer & saving address?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, customer-account, customer-address

Is their any way we can make **customer lastname as optional** while creating & saving customer,
also when we save customer address from `$order->getBillingAddress()->getData()` ?

code for reference -

```
 $billing_adress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $store          = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $storeId        = $store->getStoreId();
        $websiteId      = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer       = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($billing_adress->getEmail());
        $customer_lastname = $billing_adress->getLastname();
        if (!$customer->getId()) {
            $password = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4));
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                ->setStore($store)
                ->setFirstname($billing_adress->getFirstname())
                ->setLastname(empty($customer_lastname) ? "." : $customer_lastname)
                ->setPrefix($billing_adress->getPrefix())
                ->setEmail($billing_adress->getEmail())
                ->setPassword($password);
            $customer->save();
            /* save billing Address */
            $address = $this->addressFactory->create();
            $address->setData($order->getBillingAddress()->getData());
            $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                ->setIsDefaultShipping('0')
                ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
            $address->save();

            /* save shipping Address */
            if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
                $address = $this->addressFactory->create();
                $address->setData($order->getShippingAddress()->getData());
                $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling('0')
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
                $address->save();
                return $customer;
            }
```

Would be great to hear your thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\GuestStoreCredit\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class CustomerLastnameOptional implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['resourceConnection' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer', 'lastname', 'is_required', 0);
        $customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'lastname', 'is_required', 0);
    }
}
```